# Transaction search return AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE in PayPalAPI

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to use PayPalAPI. I create sandbox app in developer site. I got client_id and secret. Then I created `access_token`. It is work except [Transaction search](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/). I turned on Transaction Search on my application settings in developer site. However when I run this line.

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2020-01-01T00:00:00-0700&fields=all&page_size=100&page=1 \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}"
```

API returned `AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE` error.

```
{
    "name":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE",
    "message":"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.",
    "links":[
        {
            "href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error",
            "rel":"information_link"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you have any solution? Please help me!

**Update**

I don't have `transaction search` rights? How can I activate it?

```
{
"scope":"https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-buyer 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/realtimepayment 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/update-seller 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/payment/authcapture openid 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-seller 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/refund 
https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card 
https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* 
https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts 
https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks",
"access_token":"",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"app_id":"APP-80W284485P519543T",
"expires_in":30916,
"nonce":"2020-05-16T12:08:01Zz36OUNY1qTVO-EAwE6u5oT-3tWyv5-Ydr_3DuhwIpbo"
}
```

This is my settings.

[image]

Comment: Try turning it off and back on again.  And make sure you are using the right clientid:secret.  And consider why you really need to use the transaction search API; there are many reporting tools in www.paypal.com

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I turned off and on. However I couldn't get Transaction. Is there a way to get transaction from transaction id?

Comment: Access tokens refresh in 9 hours; check it now. But yes there is a way, that is much more direct. Do a get of v2/payments. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_get

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try transaction api and I try `captures_get`. I think this is better than transaction api.